# Regular Expression match based on string but do not select

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

I'm trying to use Regular Expressions to parse out some of the values of of the below example.  I am using the following pattern, `[\r\n]SVC\*\b(\w*)\b`, to select `SVC*HC` but what I ultimately want is just the `HC` part of the `SVC`.  How do I use the `SVC` in my search but only get the `HC` part?

```
REF*EA*924532~
REF*G2*733192~
SVC*HC>99214*255.45*0**1~
DTM*472*20130720~
CAS*CO*45*255.45~
REF*HPI*1111111111~
SVC*HC>59025*301*151.41**1~
DTM*472*20130720~
CAS*CO*45*149.59~
REF*HPI*1831137827~
AMT*B6*151.41~
LX*2~
```

Comment: You should escape the `*` : `var regex = @"SVC\*(\w+)";`

Comment: What should be the result after parsing upper lines? Two instances of `HC` strings?

Comment: @AhmedKRAIEM I am.  The editor removed my \.

Comment: @IlyaIvanov yes.  HC is just an example, the result could be n characters.

Comment: @collinszac10 may be you didn't use a verbatim string. Notice the `@` before the string initialization. Or you can also do `var regex = "SVC\\*(\\w+)";`

Comment: I'm kind of lazy to write a formal response, but you should look up grouping in regex. Read this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx

Comment: @AhmedKRAIEM That's not my problem.  I have the pattern working fine.  I only want a certain part of the string selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following regex...

```
(?<=[\r\n]SVC\*)\b(\w*)\b
```